# iterate through specific files zipped in a folder and move them based on text/string found in Python

Tags: python

I have multiple zipped files that I need to identify a string within the specific .html. All of the .html that I need to read end with the last 7 characters of 'bb.html'.

My goal is to move the whole .zip file if the html within contains the string/word.

I have this code written which works on the file that is listed but I need to iterate through thousands of zipped files. It doesn't have to be written as a function.

```
import os
import zipfile

        def check_files():
            os.listdir(source_folder)
            zip = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file3)
            file = zip.read("bb.html")
            if b'word' in file:
                shutil.copy(source_file3, source_folder2)
                print('word found-file moved')
            else:
                print('word not found')
```

most of the help I find iterates over the files inside, I need to iterate over ALL the .zip files and read into each bb.html file only.

I am new to Python so I have that as a challenge as well.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks so much for the answers!!!!
FINAL CODE:

```
    source_file3 = ('C:/Users/SMITH/Desktop/zipped/Message/testzip.zip')
    source_folder3 = (r'J:/server/zippedMessages')
    dest_folder = ('L:/_Mine/Zipped Messages Moved')


    def check_files():
        os.listdir(source_folder3)
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file3)
        file = zip.read("bb.html")
        if b'Health in file:
            shutil.copy(source_file3, dest_folder)
            print('word found-file moved')
        else:
            print('word not found')



    folderdir = source_folder3

    for filename in os.listdir(folderdir):
        if filename.endswith(".zip"):
            source_file3 = os.path.join(folderdir, filename)
            zip = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file3)
            check_files()
```

Comment: `for source_file3 in os.listdir(source_folder): ...`

Comment: or `for source_file3 in glob.glob(f"{source_folder}/*.zip"): ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be many examples how to iterate files in folder (not in ZIP file)

---

You should use `for`-loop with `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()`

```
for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".zip"):
        source_file3 = os.path.join(source_folder, filename)

        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file3)

        # ... code ...
```

```
for source_file3 in glob.glob(f'{source_folder}/*.zip'):

    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file3)

    # ... code ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to iterate files inside ZIP then use [ZipFile.namelist()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) or [ZipFile.infolist()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist)

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file3)

for inner_filename in zip.namelist():

    file = zip.read(inner_filename)

    # ... code ...
```

or

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file3)

for inner_fileobject in zip.infolist():

    file = zip.read(inner_fileobject)

    # ... code ...
```

Comment: I can iterate over the zips, I can print things about them-name, length, etc, but I can't get my code to iterate over them and look inside them. that's where I'm stuck. I can only get my code to work on the very first one by finding the keyword and moving it. But, I need a code to look at the first .zip, read into it, move it if needed, go to next file. How do I use my code to iterate through them-I have the file named and I'm not sure how to leave that out and still look inside the html.

Comment: your description was misleading for me. It looks like you ask how to iterate files inside ZIP, not files files on disk. See: [ZipFile.namelist()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) or [ZipFile.infolist()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist)

Comment: I apologize. I am just wanting to perform the same action as above on many files not just get the info about them.  I’ll keep searching. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to repeate the same on many zip files then you need first part of my answer. That's all.

Comment: Thank you furas for the answer. Got it to work!!!! Appreciate your time.